# Find the coordinates of the points where the line $4y = 7x + 1$ intersects the curve $x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 4y = 60$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried equating the two equations to each other and then solving for x; however, I believe this is not correct.  I also tried factorizing the curve equation but I could not see a way through.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you believe that "it" is not correct? I would indeed just put $y= \frac{7x+1}{4}$ to the second equation, and then evaluate ...

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is fine. Since$$4y=7x+1\iff y=\frac74x+\frac14$$you can replace $y$ with $\frac74x+\frac14$ in the second equation, thereby getting $\frac{5}{16} \left(13 x^2-26 x-3\right)$. And now you solve the equation$$\frac{5}{16} \left(13 x^2-26 x-3\right)=60,$$which has two solutions: $-3$ and $5$. So, the intersection points are $(-3,-5)$ and $(5,9)$.

Comment: I realise to get the answer I must have the equation In a quadratic form and the use the formula for its solution. I am still having difficulty seeing how I can get to 5/16(132−26−3)=60.

Comment: Like I said: in the expression $x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 4y$, replace each $y$ with $\frac74x+\frac14$. Then, simplify the expression.

Comment: I have been able to simplify the expression now and arrived at the two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Given  $\space\mathbf{4y} = 7x + 1 \quad\land\quad
 x^2 - 2x + y^2 - 4y = 60\implies \mathbf{4y}= x^2 - 2x + y^2 -60$

$$ 7x + 1 =x^2 - 2x + y^2 -60\\ 
\implies x^2-9x+y^2-61=0\\
\implies y = \pm\sqrt{61-x^2 + 9 x}
\quad \text{for}\quad (9-x)x\le 61
$$
There are $12$ integer solutions easily verified with a spreadsheet or [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7x+%2B+1+%3Dx%5E2+-+2x+%2B+y%5E2+-60+)

$(x,y)\in\big\{(-4,\pm3)\quad (-3,\pm5)\quad (4,\pm9)\quad 
(5,\pm9)\quad (12,\pm 5)\quad (13,\pm3)\big\}$